# How to find a child div which isn't hidden

Tags: jquery

I have the code:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="firstchild" style="display:none">
   <div id="secondchild">
   <div id="thirdchild" style="display:none">
</div>
```

So what I want to do is find the element in jquery that isn't hidden ie. secondchild.

I'm guess I sould use something along the lines of :hidden but I'm actually wanting to do the opposite and find the non hidden one.

Would anyone know how to do this? To find the visible div that is a child of parent and make it hidden?

Comment: Look at the attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try the `:visible` selector:

```
$('#parent div:visible').hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

Luckily there's a `visible` too:

```
$('#parent > :visible').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to hide the visible element(s), then there's no point specifically finding them. Instead you can simply hide all potential elements unconditionally.

```
$('#parent > div').hide();
```

Those child divs that were visible are now hidden. Those that were are already hidden are still hidden.

- In one respect, this is inefficient - it hides elements that were already hidden.
- In another respect it is efficient - it doesn't waste effort identifying the visible div(s).

In practice, there's not much to choose between this and a specific hide. In both cases, all potential elements must be addressed - either to read them or write to them or both.